# Ideas for Realistic Sample Content for Demo Site

Tags: nodes

I have a couple of drupal interviews coming up.  Not that this is an excuse, but it is my excuse--  Since I have worked on sites for other companies, I don't have my own body of work to display, meaning I don't have a portfolio of sites that I have created from beginning to end for specific clients.

In preparation for these interviews,I have created four sites, but what is killing me is the content.  I set the sites up and use devel generate to get dummy content in, so I can see how things will look, but my recruiters are saying, and I agree, I need realistic text/content.  This part is killing me, trying to make so much stuff up.

I have gone to sites to basically "borrow" and modify their content.

I want to see if anyone else has a better method for adding realistic content to their demo drupal sites.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not really a drupal specific question, but there is endless information on the internet you can use (essentially copy and paste), just avoid copyrighted materials. Pick a topic, for example you might choose animals, then pull up a bunch of wikipedia pages about that topic and copy & paste into drupal.

Comment: hummm Wikipedia - had not thought of that at all.  Think I am nearly brain dead - creating the drupal sites with feeds,panels and views is nothing compared to coming up with fresh realistic text.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding content, not Drupal.

Comment: Since I am creating several sites in Drupal, I don't consider this off top.

Comment: I've noticed this on [downgrade/on-hold] practice several boards lately.  Not every question is always directly related to a drupal view, panel, media, feed module, etc.  Drupal of a web framework, hence some questions are related to best practice.  And we are looking to some drupalers who has previous experience with a particular topic/issue.  As I have seen mentioned on various review boards, it may be easier to just go to Odesk.

Comment: You could use the [Puzzler module](https://www.drupal.org/project/puzzler) to quickly add images and texts (via Wikipedia API) to your Drupal pages, blocks, views, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take content from other sites on the website, just make sure you are taking content you are legally allowed to use so you aren't breaching copyright.

I would recommend using content from Wikipedia to make your pages as you can an extreme amount of information there to make professional looking content.

For information on the legalities of using Wikipedia content, see [Wikipedia:Reusing Wikipedia content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReusing_Wikipedia_content).

Comment: Any comments to go with the down vote?

Comment: And I will be sure to make a note to reference the actual content.  Don't like being in confined places for long.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Realistic - if you mean word and letter distribution, at least - filler text in the industry is called [Lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum).

> In publishing and graphic design, [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) is a placeholder text commonly used to demonstrate the graphic elements of a document or visual presentation. By replacing the distraction of meaningful content with filler text of scrambled Latin it allows viewers to focus on graphical elements such as font, typography, and layout.

There is a Drupal 8 module for it, called simply [ipsum](https://drupal.org/project/ipsum), based on now-unmaintained but basically still working [Drupal Ipsum](https://drupal.org/project/drupal_ipsum).

Also, good old [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module has a Generate submodule with it's own lorem ipsum style generator:

> Accelerate development of your site or module by quickly generating nodes, comments, terms, users, and more.

## Never use actual content from 3rd party sites

without proper permission and proper disclaimer. There are 2 major legal reasons:

1. It is good old copyright violation, just as if you would take a song by someone else, put it in your musical and never told anyone...
2. If you will get a job or commission by pretending something is your work, when it isn't, even if it was a negligible part of work, in many countries it will count as [fraud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraud). Up to 8 years in prison where I live.

Comment: He already has lorem ipsum via devel generate though and wants something better. To be honest lorem ipsum / devel generate type content is about as far from professional looking content as you can get.

Comment: @rooby if someone thinks that about 500 years of usage by professionals in industry (printing first, of course) is "as far from professional looking content as you can get", his choice. And if OP does not want any Drupal answer, then this question shouldn't be here at all in the first place.

Comment: He didn't way he didn't want a drupal answer (although his question is definitely not drupal specific), he just said he already tried devel generate. I have not experienced any clients that think lorem ipsum is good. Most say "What is that weird text". Devel generated images are also not great. 500 years of usage doesn't mean aesthetically good. It could mean many things, like easy for example, or not many alternatives.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your responses, even though so many people are anxious to down grade questions these days.  As rooby said, I have used devel-generate and it's great to get you going when u r setting up views, panels and faceted searches, etc, but clients want to see "real" content because for some reason, they get lost in the "sample text" idea.  I like your idea, rooby's, of using wiki-think that will give me enough data/text to build off off.  some mention images above - check out the module drupal "lorempixel" it is nice for getting less generic images into your site.  Thanks again.

Comment: lorempixel is better (there are also a bunch of other similar services), but still not as good as manually created content.